# Extracting specific characters from specific column in R dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to extract gene name from a column names as "Proteins" in dataframe in R.
My Datafame is like this.

[image]

```
Scan    Proteins
1   7:: [sp|P02787|TRFE_HUMAN Serotransferrin OS=Homo sapiens GN=TF PE=1 SV=3 ||| sp|TRFE_HUMAN| ||| tr|B4DHZ6|B4DHZ6_HUMAN Transferrin, isoform CRA_c OS=Homo sapiens GN=TF PE=2 SV=1]
2   21:: [sp|P01876|IGHA1_HUMAN Ig alpha-1 chain C region OS=Homo sapiens GN=IGHA1 PE=1 SV=2 ||| sp|P01877|IGHA2_HUMAN Ig alpha-2 chain C region OS=Homo sapiens GN=IGHA2 PE=1 SV=3]
3   2:: [sp|P14543|NID1_HUMAN Nidogen-1 OS=Homo sapiens GN=NID1 PE=1 SV=3 ||| tr|B4DM05|B4DM05_HUMAN cDNA FLJ51241, highly similar to Nidogen-1 OS=Homo sapiens PE=2 SV=1]
```

I want to get only 1st gene name (eg, for Scan1, TF, for Scan2, IGHA1).
How can I do this in R?

Any comment is helpful for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A straight-forward regex does this:

```r
dat <- data.frame(Scan=1:3, Proteins=c("7:: [sp|P02787|TRFE_HUMAN Serotransferrin OS=Homo sapiens GN=TF PE=1 SV=3 ||| sp|TRFE_HUMAN| ||| tr|B4DHZ6|B4DHZ6_HUMAN Transferrin, isoform CRA_c OS=Homo sapiens GN=TF PE=2 SV=1]", "21:: [sp|P01876|IGHA1_HUMAN Ig alpha-1 chain C region OS=Homo sapiens GN=IGHA1 PE=1 SV=2 ||| sp|P01877|IGHA2_HUMAN Ig alpha-2 chain C region OS=Homo sapiens GN=IGHA2 PE=1 SV=3]", "2:: [sp|P14543|NID1_HUMAN Nidogen-1 OS=Homo sapiens GN=NID1 PE=1 SV=3 ||| tr|B4DM05|B4DM05_HUMAN cDNA FLJ51241, highly similar to Nidogen-1 OS=Homo sapiens PE=2 SV=1]"))

gsub("^.*GN=([^ ]+).*", "\\1", dat$Proteins)
# [1] "TF"    "IGHA2" "NID1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some string extraction powered by regular expressions.

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  mutate(Gene = str_extract(Protein, pattern = "GN=[a-zA-Z0-9]*")) %>%
  mutate(Gene = str_extract(Gene, pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]*"))
```

Here is a break down of the regular expression:

```
GN=     # pattern starts with GN=
[       # begin a grouping
a-z     # any lowercase letter
A-Z     # any uppercase letter
0-9     # any digit
]       # end grouping
*       # the group can repeat
```

So this regular expression looks for any string that has any number of alphanumeric characters so long as it follows a `GN=`. The second `mutate()` removes the `GN=` from the front of the string.

Comment: Thank you very much for prompt reply!. "transmute" and "str_extract" was helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using data from @r2evans. You can try this approach

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr) 
dat %>% 
  transmute(Scan,GENE = str_extract(Proteins, "(?<=GN=)\\w+(?=\\s)"))
#   Scan  GENE
# 1    1    TF
# 2    2 IGHA1
# 3    3  NID1
```

- `(?<=GN=)`: match behind `GN=`
- `\\w`: match word characters at least one time